# Expand Collapse Menu on Mobile While Maintaining Hover on Desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html page on my desktop that uses a vertical sliding menu on hover. On an iPad I can click the menu to expand it, but I can't figure out how to make it collapse. I have tried using jquery but I can't seem to make it work. Here is the code I am starting with.

```css
#navigation_slideout {
 position: fixed;
 top: 80px;
 left: -370px;
 -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
 -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
 -o-transition-duration: .5s;
 transition-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
 box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
}

 #navigation_slideout:hover {
  left: -39px;
}

#navigation_slideout ul
 {
 list-style: none;
 }

#navigation_slideout ul li {
 background: #548EBE;
 width: 325px;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: left;
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-family:HelveticaNeue,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 12pt;
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;

}
#navigation_slideout ul li a{
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight:bold;
 display: block;
 background-color:#548EBE;
 color:white;
}
#navigation_slideout ul li ul{ 

width:285px;
}

#navigation_slideout ul li ul li { 

width:10px;
position:relative;
left:-41px;
}


#navigation_slideout ul li ul li a { 
background:#548EBE;
width:326px;
height:30px;
text-align:left;
padding-top:5px;
font-family:  helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12pt;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
}

#menu{
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
 transform: rotate(-90deg); 
 font-family:HelveticaNeue,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 14pt;
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 right:0px;
 padding:0px 0px 0px 0px

}

#menu a{
  font-size: 14pt;
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-decoration:none;
}

table.nospacing { 
border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;


} 
table.nospacing th, td {
 padding: 0;
  }
  .menu-col{max-width: 30px;}
```

```html
<div id="navigation_slideout" style="background-color:#548EBE;z-index:1" >
<table class="nospacing" style="border-style:none">
<tr>
<td>

  <ul>
   <li><a href="default.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="about/default.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;About</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact/default.html" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contacts</a></li>   
   <li><a href="faq/default.html" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FAQs</a></li>
  </ul>
  <hr width="200px"/>
  <ul>
  <!-- #BeginEditable "redlines" -->
   <li style="display:none"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Redlines</a></li>   
  <!-- #EndEditable -->   
  </ul>
  </td>
    <td   class="menu-col" style="border-left:medium;border-left-color:white;border-left-style:solid"><p id="menu"><a href="#">MENU</a></p></td>

</tr>
</table>​
```

Answer (score 0):

iDevices have a wierd thing where where the hover state persists. I fixed this by adding hover classes. If you are using jquery you can do this...

```
elem.on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}

elem.on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
}
```

there are other fixes aswell...

http://davidwalsh.name/ios-hover-menu-fix

http://www.slickmedia.co.uk/news/blog/glenns-blog/fix-ipad-iphone-css-hover-issues/

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply this to my code. Do I just copy into my jquery script section or do I need to modify it in some way?

Comment: so add that to your jquery script, and then in your css, where you use #navigation_slideout:hover, change it to #navigation_slideout.hover instead. This is basically removing the :hover state dependency and doing the same thing using classes